# Is this correct mysqli

Tags: mysql

Is this correct, I know you aren't supposed to use mysql anymore. So I just added i to the end, this was code I got from the internet, and I am new to mysql so I'm not quite sure what I am doing. I just want to make sure this is correct usage.

```
$sql = "SELECT lat, lon from zipcodes_2011 WHERE zipcode='$zip'";
  $r = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  if (!$r) {
     $this->last_error = mysqli_error();
     return false;
  } else {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
     mysqli_free_result($r);
     return $row;       
  }
```

Comment: Almost correct in that it won't fail except for the `mysqli_error()` call, but not _recommended_ if `$zip` is derived from user input. If it is, you ought to be using a MySQLi prepared statement instead of calling `mysqli_query()` with a concatenated/interpolated SQL statement. [Start learning how to do this now](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), as you really ought to be doing it all the time.

Comment: I have already started to learn prepared statements, this is code I got from the internet, but you are right that would be much better, I will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is incorrect.

Looking at the documentation for [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php): it states that `mysqli $link` is not optional. You must pass the database link to it.

```
$this->last_error = mysqli_error($con);
```

I would also highly recommend preparing this.

```
$sql = "SELECT `lat`,`lon` FROM `zipcodes_2011` WHERE `zipcode` = ?";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

$error = mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
if ($error === false) {
    $this->last_error = mysqli_error($con);
    return false;
}

$error = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $zip);
if ($error === false) {
    $this->last_error = mysqli_error($con);
    return false;
}

$error = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if ($error === false) {
    $this->last_error = mysqli_error($con);
    return false;
}

$error = mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row);
if ($error === false) {
    $this->last_error = mysqli_error($con);
    return false;
}

$error = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
if ($error === false) {
    $this->last_error = mysqli_error($con);
    return false;
}

return $row;
```